# Automatticly scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have yet another question about my website.
When you enter it (http://van-der-noord.nl/beta) You see an image. After a couple of seconds, it scrolls a bit down. First I had another image so it went well but with this image, you see only one line of text. Can I make it that I see all three lines of text?
I tried moving the

```
<a id="#image">
```

### but it just went weird..

So right now it is like this when you enter the site (this is still good):

[image: when you enter the site]

But then after a couple of seconds it scrolls down (which I want), but it is like this [image: not good]
I would want it to be like this [image: good]

Or another option is that the heart would just go away after a couple of seconds, like this [image: no heart]

I'm not including a jsfiddle but I could send you a link to a dropboxfile with all the resources of the site of you need it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry it's in Dutch...

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more with details ?

Comment: Okay I'll try to do that

Comment: Yes, I saw it. In my screen (15 inches) resolution (1280*800) I saw the heart image only when it scrolled down. It did not show that single line of text which you saw.

Comment: O that's even worse ;) but how do I fix it?

Comment: I saw you have not taken in consideration of different screen sizes while developing.

Comment: Well this is a concept my official site does work with all screen sizes as far as I know but I'm just experimenting I'll optimize it later for every screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease the image width (maybe to 80% from 93%) and please check. I hope it will be solved.

```
<h2>
    <img width="93%" height="93%" src="images/hart.png">
</h2>
```

Comment: Great Dude @RobinvanderNoord